# What are some places that have never recorded an "ice day" nor a "tropical night"?

Tags: climate

An ice day is a day on which the maximum temperature doesn't exceed 0 °C and a tropical night is a night on which the minimum temperature exceeds 20 °C. Probably no part of the tropics has experienced an ice day and most continental locations far north haven't experienced a tropical night. My guess is that a location that has experienced neither would have to be coastal or an island in the mid-latitudes: Eureka, California, is one example (the coldest day was 1°C and the warmest night 17 °C). Campbell island (NZ) and Tristan Da Cunha might also be examples, but I couldn't find exact data to prove it.

Comment: You'd have to define "never" - in recorded history? Since the formation of the earth?

Comment: you might want to update your kowledge about tropical nights in the arctic.

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me (other than the "never")... basically the answer should be: very maritime locales near continually modest water temperatures?  Because you're only allowing for about 25°C range over the course of the year.

Comment: Never was imprecise. Let's go with never recorded in modern times (for example, since 1850).

Comment: @trondhansen it's conjecture of course, but even in the country we originate from tropical nights are rare. I would say it's unlikely that places like Tynset and Karasjok have ever had one.